# Select rows that have a value matching any one of multiple rows from a second table

Tags: mysql

Still a mySQL beginner. I have two tables, `follows` and `events`, that have these columns:

```
FOLLOWS
user | profile

EVENTS
user | profile | other_stuff
```

I want to get a list of relevant events from `events` based who the user is following.

`SELECT * FROM follows WHERE user = $userId` retrieves the people that the user is following.
Now how can I select all the rows in `events` where `profile` matches the value of `profile` from *any* of the people that the user is following?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Even if it doesn't work correctly show us what you've got so far...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
select * 
from follows f
join events e on e.user = f.user
where f.user = $userId
```